# how to write simple txt testcases in java

Tags: java, bash, redirect, testcase

Hi I'm writing my first Java app and I've got a few Testcases (*.tc files) I want to direct to the app via this script:

```
for f in `ls *.tc`; do
  echo "Current Testcase: $f"
  x=${f%.*}
  java Main < $x.tc > $x.out

  if diff "$x.out" "$x.should"; then
    echo "passed testcase $f"
    let PASSED=PASSED+1
  else
    echo "failed testcase $f"
    let FAILED=FAILED+1
 fi
done
```

The Problem is I can't quite figure out why as soon as the `tc file` contains more than one line the app goes nuts. For example: `quit.tc` contains

```
quit
```

and works just like when I manually enter "quit", therfore the testcase passes.
However when I write another tc: `quit2.tc` which contains

```
lala
test
quit
```

The app quits after the first command (because the readString function seems to return null afterwards).
Here is the function responsible for reading:

```
public String readString(){

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String answer = null;

try {
  answer = br.readLine();
  return answer;
}
catch(IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println("IO Error");
}
return answer;
}
```

I dont know why or when this function returns null when I redirect to the app, which seems to be the problem. Can you help out so I can get the tc script working? thx

Comment: Is this _all_ of your code?  You don't seem to be calling the `readString()` method in your test script...  Also, you're not doing yourself any favors by creating new readers every time the method is called - the overhead of creation is probably going to offset any gain from using buffering.  And try running this through debug - because of the `try-catch`, you could still be returning null, if you're getting an error.

Comment: From your script perspective, the `for loop` will mess up when you have space in your file names. Do `for f in *.tc` and use " " around variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're new to java, and you still shape your style and way of doing things, I will recommend you 2 tips:

1) use [Scanner](http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html) to read your input. Using [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method of the Scanner object is probably what you're looking for.

2) design your code, so that it's testable via [JUnit](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html).

Still, in your `readString()` method, remove the `return answer;` from the try block.

UPDATE: try to implement the following in your function:

**a)** while the scanner instance hasNextLine() is true ->

**b)** call scanner instance nextLine() method ->

**c)** parse the line, and see if it equals 'quit' ->

**d)** implement the corresponding logical `if` cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `BufferedReader`: It will read the whole file at once (for performance reasons).

Since you create a new `BufferedReader` each time `readString()` is called, the first reader will swallow most of the file (or all of it) and the second reader will hit end-of-file.

The solution is to put the reader into a field, create it *once* and then always use the same reader to call `readLine()`

Plus you never close the reader.

Java will forget unused objects but you must properly close OS resources like `FileInputStream`s